# Value is Blank when taking input from HTML to Javascript

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5phSo.png)

Whenever I am putting some input in the input box, I am not able to get input from HTML.
When I am doing console.log(text) it is blank.

```
<input type="number" id="text">

<script>
        var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
        console.log(text);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the input field's value on page load, which is a blank string since there is no value in the input at that time.

You can instead get the value when the `input` event is fired:

```html
<input type="number" id="text">

<script>
text.addEventListener('input', function(){
  console.log(this.value)
})
 </script>
```

To store the value in a variable, you can assign the variable the value of the input field in the event listener:

```html
<input type="number" id="text">

<script>
  var val;
  text.addEventListener('input', function() {
    val = this.value;
    console.log(val)
  })
</script>
```

Comment: How can I store the value of the input value in another variable?

Comment: You can make a global variable and set the value of that variable in the callback function

Comment: @AzizurRahman I've updated my answer to demonstrate how.